# Is tf.linalg.svd differentiable?

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, svd

I'd like to use tf.linalg.svd to convert my input matrix(8,4) to two matrixes with the shape ( 8,5)and (5,4) for the calculation of loss. Is this possible or there won't be any gradients?I am using tensorflow 2.9